# Dynamically importing Python modules

Tags: python, import

I am trying to import the members of a module whose name is not known. Instead of

```
import foo
```

I am using:

```
__import__("foo")
```

How can I achieve a similar thing for the `from foo import bar` case instead of resorting to an "eval"?

**Update:** It seems `fromlist` did the trick. Is there a way to emulate `from foo import *`? `fromlist=['*']` didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To emulate `from foo import *` you could use `dir` to get the attributes of the imported module:

```
foo = __import__('foo')
for attr in dir(foo):
    if not attr.startswith('_'):
        globals()[attr] = getattr(foo, attr)
```

Using `from foo import *` is generally frowned upon, and emulating it even more so, I'd imagine.

Comment: +1 I'm using __builtins__ rather than globals() so that I can use this code from another module.

Answer (score 9):

```
__import__("foo", fromlist=["bar"])
```

for more information `help(__import__)`

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to emulate "from foo import *"?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically import with the help of [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__). There are `fromlist` key argument in `__import__` to call `from foo import bar`.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to emulate "from foo import *"?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to import one of many configuration files, each of which had different values for the same named variables, dicts, etc.

You can't just do this:

```
def mother_function(module, *args, **kwargs):
    from module import variable
    return variable

def call_home_to_mamma():
    import module_42
    return mother_function(module_42)
```

The explanation as to why this doesn't work is above my pay grade, and involves closures and namespaces.  What I found worked was to call the mother function with 'module_name' as a string argument, then dyamically import the particular variable when I really needed it:

```
def mother_function(module_name, *args, **kwargs):
    exec('from %s import %s' % (module_name, variable))
    variable = eval(variable)
    return variable

def call_home_to_mamma():
    import module_42
    return mother_function(module_42.__name__)
```

Bingo.... you have dyamic import of any variable you want, from an imported module as determined at runtime.