# Creating Python Façade Package

Tags: python, package

I'm not sure how to describe this, but is there a way to create an façade package that handles multiple versions of a internal package?

Consider:

```
Foo/
    __init__.py
    A/
       Bar/
       __init__.py
       etc.
    B/
       Bar/
       __init__.py
       etc.
    C/
       Bar/    
       __init__.py
       etc.
```

Inside Package's `__init__.py` I have python logic to append the sys.path to point to one of the Bar packages depending on the runtime configuration.  This leaves me using two python import statements.

```
import Foo
import Bar
```

Can I reduce that to one import statement and treat Foo as a façade for the correct version of Bar.  The only was I have found is based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783691/dynamically-importing-python-modules).  In foo.py's `__init__.py`:

```
for attr in dir(bar):
    globals()[attr] = getattr(bar, attr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend against modifying `system.path` since that can have implications for unrelated code.

You can get this behavior by using `sys.modules`.  When a module is imported, it is registered in the `sys.modules` dictionary.  You can accomplish this simply by setting the entry for the proxy module when it is imported.

implementation.py:

```
def method():
    print "implemented method"
```

proxy.py:

```
if __name__ != '__main__':
    import sys
    import implementation
    sys.modules[__name__] = implementation
```

main.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import proxy
    proxy.method()
```

output:

```
$ python main.py 
implemented method
```